# Verifying self signed certificate in openssl

Tags: ssl-certificate

I type the following command

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect servername:443
```

In the SSL session I get the certificates and

```
Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)
```

I have a program that is using the certificate to talk to the server, but is not able to ..it says

```
Error: Failed to initiate SSL handshake with peer. There is possibly problem with your your SSL certificate.
```

I have another server and an openssl command gives Verify return code: 0 (ok) and the program connects to it with no problem.

I donot know how the program(c++ program) is trying to connect to the servers. But does anybody know any of the possible reasons why it is not able to connect to a server with self signed certificate?

Comment: Have you tried to simulate the request using curl to see if the same problem happens? E.g if you are trying to POST to a WebService: `curl -k -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" -H "SOAPAction: yourAction" --data-binary @payload.xml --user user:pass 
 https://youraddress/`

Comment: I get Warning: Couldn't read data from file "payload.xml", this makes an empty POST.
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   145  100   145    0     0    145      0  0:00:01 --:--:--  0:00:01   331<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2f">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>

Comment: You should create the file payload.xml with the xml content you want to POST to the server.

Comment: Consider adding `-v`to curl parameters to increase the verbose level.